# Formatting Results of Excel .iqy Web Query

Tags: windows, excel

I need to format the results of a web query .iqy file in Excel.

Here's what the .iqy file looks like:

```
WEB
1
http://www.mdl.nws.noaa.gov/~BMA-SREF/data/text/sref_2-M_TMP_["CURRDATE","Click cell where (YYYYMMDD) is"]03.txt
Selection=All
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=False
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

Right now, all the results are going into Column A, even though there are 5+ columns in the actual text file. I need the results to be delimited in the worksheet after the web query is completed.

Comment: I'll just add that the original URL in the above example is not working, but using [any CSV file](https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Gross-domestic-product/Gross-domestic-product-March-2022-quarter/Download-data/Gross-domestic-product-March-2022-quarter-visualisation-csv.csv) will also have the same result.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Apologies for tagging you here, but it's not possible to tag you in [your](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73443639/5298879) [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377396/5298879) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51286116/5298879) until you comment or post there. Did you resurrect them randomly, to offload points on something you just consider worth revisiting, or are you facing challenges similar to those and you'd be able to provide some additional details, specific to your case? There's no description beyond "JM-AGMS wants to draw more attention to this question".

Answer (score 0):

Set PreFormattedTextToColumns=True

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Excel has trouble understanding how to handle files with delimited data for some reason, and it's not a problem with the .iqy file.

If you have control over the source of the file, the closest thing to a solution is to prepend `sep=<delimiter>` to the data so that it looks like this (assuming comma-delimited data):

```
sep=,
a,b,c
1,2,3
```

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel/730509#730509