# How to test rollbacks in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions, pytest

I have a problem with test isolation when testing a logic, that involves a transaction rollback in SQLAlchemy.

**Model**:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company = db.Column(db.Text)
    subtype = db.Column(db.Text)

    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint(company, subtype),)
```

**View**:

```
def create():
    instance = Product(**request.json)
    db.session.add(instance)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()
        return {"detail": "Product object already exists", "status": 406, "title": "Duplicate object"}, 406
    return {"uri": f"/products/{instance.id}"}, 201
```

**Tests**:

```
DEFAULT_DATA = {"company": "Test", "subtype": "Sub"}


def test_create(client):
    response = client.post("/products", json=DEFAULT_DATA)
    assert response.status_code == 201
    instance = Product.query.one()
    assert response.json == {"uri": f"/products/{instance.id}"}


def test_create_duplicate(client):
    response = client.post("/products", json=DEFAULT_DATA)
    assert response.status_code == 201

    instance = Product.query.one()
    assert response.json == {"uri": f"/products/{instance.id}"}
    response = client.post("/products", json=DEFAULT_DATA)
    assert response.status_code == 406
    assert response.json == {"detail": "Product object already exists", "status": 406, "title": "Duplicate object"}
```

**conftest.py**:

```
import flask_migrate
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import event

from project.app import create_connexion_app
from project.models import db


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def connexion_app():
    return create_connexion_app("project.settings.TestSettings")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app(connexion_app):
    app = connexion_app.app
    with app.app_context():
        yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", name="db")
def db_setup(app):
    flask_migrate.upgrade()

    yield db

    flask_migrate.downgrade()
    db.engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alembic_version")


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def session(db):
    with db.engine.connect() as connection:

        @event.listens_for(db.session, "after_transaction_end")
        def restart_savepoint(session, transaction):
            if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
                # ensure that state is expired the way
                # session.commit() at the top level normally does
                # (optional step)
                session.expire_all()
                session.begin_nested()

        transaction = connection.begin()

        db.session.begin_nested()

        yield db.session

        db.session.rollback()
        db.session.close()

        if transaction.is_active:
            transaction.rollback()
```

`SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN` is set to `False`

The second test is failing with the following output:

```
    def test_create_duplicate(client):
        response = client.post("/products", json=DEFAULT_DATA)
>       assert response.status_code == 201
E       AssertionError: assert 406 == 201
E        +  where 406 = <<class 'pytest_flask.plugin.JSONResponse'> streamed [406 NOT ACCEPTABLE]>.status_code
```

Relevant PG log:

```
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO product (company, subtype) VALUES ('Test', 'Sub') RETURNING product.id
LOG:  statement: COMMIT
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: SELECT product.id AS product_id, product.company AS product_company, product.subtype AS product_subtype
    FROM product
    WHERE product.id = 1
LOG:  statement: SELECT product.id AS product_id, product.company AS product_company, product.subtype AS product_subtype
    FROM product
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO product (company, subtype) VALUES ('Test', 'Sub') RETURNING product.id
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_company_subtype_key"
DETAIL:  Key (company, subtype)=(Test, Sub) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO product (company, subtype) VALUES ('Test', 'Sub') RETURNING product.id
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
```

So, the first test commits a row into the DB and it is not rolled back between tests, thus db state is not restored between runs.

Other tests, without involving an explicit rollback work fine. Tried to change `SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN` to `True` and use `flush` instead of `commit`, but in this case the tests after `test_create_duplicate` are affected.

How to setup a test suite for testing such code, that involves manual commiting / rolling back?

**Packages**:

- Flask==1.0.2
- Flask-Migrate==2.2.1
- Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
- SQLAlchemy==1.2.9
- dictalchemy==0.1.2.7
- connexion==1.4.2
- pytest==3.6.2
- pytest-flask==0.10.0

**Python version**: 3.6.6

**RDBMS**: PostgreSQL 10.4

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the transactions here.
The first test runs, without issues and commits all changes to the database (with the commit in the view function).
The test setup has nothing to roll back since the transaction is done.
When the second test starts your database is no longer empty and the creation fails.

To get around this there are a few things you can do:
1) If you have a lot of 'setup' data you can dump your sqlite to memory in the session db and restore that everytime at the end of the session
2) you can truncate all tables the end of the session

Comment: This cannot be reproduced using PostgreSQL 10.4, but can be reproduced [with SQLite](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#pysqlite-serializable). There must be something you're doing wrong that is not mentioned. *The question should be updated to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: @aaron Can you elaborate on why it cannot be reproduced on PostgreSQL 10.4?

Comment: @Zegarek Nested transactions and the rollback work on PostgreSQL 10.4. Did you manage to reproduce it?

Comment: @aaron I didn't try but I also don't really see anything that shouldn't work on PostgreSQL 10.4 or even earlier. I was curious what exactly it was that you found about OP's code that made you say *This cannot be reproduced using PostgreSQL 10.4* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286116/how-to-test-rollbacks-in-sqlalchemy?noredirect=1#comment137006048_51286116) and in your [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77674747/5298879), as well as why you insist it must be SQLite, both contrary to what OP stated.

Comment: I am not insisting it must be SQLite, that's precisely why I deleted my answer and instead asked in question comments for the code necessary to reproduce the problem (with PostgreSQL), as I do for interesting questions that cannot be reproduced and thus are unanswerable as-is.